# My percentage calculation is showing wrong result

Tags: c#, .net

I am calculating percentage for certain amount, my code is:

```
calc = ((tax / 100) * amount);
```

where tax=5, amount=1000 and all are long values the result expected is 50 but i am getting a 0

Can any one help me, where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Result of integer division (`5 / 100`) is 0, make sure it is floating point division:

```
calc = ((tax / 100.0) * amount);
// or
calc = ((tax / 100f) * amount);
```

Comment: Alternatively do the multiplication followed by the division

Comment: @Akshay: It may be working as you expect, but I don't think it's *correct*. See my answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you so much for your explanation it is really helpful for me but sorry i asked wrong question.I am calculating 5% of 1000

Comment: @Akshay: So you're *not* calculating a percentage. You're calculating an amount *given* a percentage. I'll delete my answer - but please be careful in future to write questions more clearly. Otherwise you just waste people's time. (I still think you should be using `decimal`, by the way.)

Comment: @Akshay @JonSkeet I agree that in this case it should be `decimal`, I also think that those variable types should be included in question.

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
calc = (( (float)tax / 100) * amount);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your dividing the integers then you will get the result Zero instead of Decimal(percentage).

(tax / 100)..... is calculated as an integral value; any fractional part is removed.

In your case 5/100 = 0.05. It will remove the .05 and the result is 0

Fallow the [Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/cbb0c38d-5581-4615-9beb-58d68a1e8f50), Same exammple provided there.